# Lattices of Partial Order Set Segmentation Fault(core dumped)

Tags: c, graph, linked-list, relation

Given a Set S = {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,….} whose size is n (< 20), I need to list all the lattices (subsets of S) on S with size k(should be taken as input, but in my question I fixed it for debugging purposes). The relation over which the partial order is defined is divisibility.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}node;

void addEdge(node* graph[],int a,int b){
    node *ptr=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr->next=graph[a];
    ptr->data=b;
    graph[a]=ptr;
}

void buildGraph(node* graph[],int n){

    int i,j;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=i/2;j++){
            if(i%j==0){
                if(j!=1) addEdge(graph,i/j,i);
                else addEdge(graph,j,i);
            }
        }
    }
}

void printGraph(node* graph[],int n){
    int i=0;
    node *ptr;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
        ptr=graph[i];
        printf("Row-%d ",i);
        while(ptr!=NULL){
            printf("%d ",ptr->data);
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void print(int array[],int n){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%d ",array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

bool checkDuplicate(int array[],int n,int a){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) if(array[i]==a) return false;
    return true;
}
void formLattice(node* graph[],int lattice[],int k,int vertex,int level){
    //printf("Level-%d \n",level);
    if(level>k) return;
    if(level==k) {
        lattice[level-1]=vertex;
        print(lattice,k);
        return;
    }
    lattice[level-1]=vertex;
    node* ptr=graph[vertex];
    while(ptr!=NULL){
    //  if(checkDuplicate(lattice,level,ptr->data))
        formLattice(graph,lattice,k,ptr->data,level+1);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}
void printLattice(node* graph[],int n,int k){
    int lattice[k],i;
    node* ptr;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        ptr=graph[i];
        while(ptr!=NULL){
            lattice[0]=i;
            formLattice(graph,lattice,k,ptr->data,2);
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
    }
}
int main(void) {

    int n=10,k=4;
    node* graph[n+1];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++) graph[i]=NULL;
    buildGraph(graph,n);
//  printGraph(graph,n); // Comment to print out the Hasse Diagram
    printLattice(graph,n,k);
    return 0;
}
```

Showing Segementation Fault(core dumped)
Any idea why is this happening so?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The code of `formLattice()` has evidences that only those vertexes are probed for `lattice[level]` that are connected to `lattice[level-1]`. Not every lattice, of course, has a total order on it (namely {1,2,3,6} doesnt). How can the present program choose the vertex 3 for `lattice[2]` while the vertex 2 is stored into `lattice[1]`?

In other words, there must be another loop, going for *all* already chosen vertexes in `lattice` from `0` to `level-1`, around the present loop for `ptr`.